# Limit of repeated $\sin$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering if it was possible to formalize the following. If we let $f_n(x)$ denote the sequence of function so that $f_1(x)=\sin(x)$, $f_2(x)=\sin(\sin(x))$, $f_3(x)=\sin(\sin(\sin(x)))$ and so on. Does this sequence of functions have a limit? Is there a theory that could explain the behaviour of repeating trigonometric functions?

Comment: Whoops, tried searching. Thank you @MartinR

Comment: When I was a kid, we used to take one of those clumsy calculators with big buttons, enter some arbitrary number, press down the "Sin" button with a brick and leave it for an hour or so, in an attempt to answer the same question.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this is a neat application of the [Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).  It turns out that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x) = 0
$$
So that the sequence of functions $f_n$ converge pointwise to $f(x) = 0$.  In fact, it can be shown that this convergence is uniform.

A slightly more interesting case is that of $f_1(x) = \cos(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $|\sin x|<|x|$ for $x\neq0$, hence the limit exists. Can it be not equal to 0?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you! Mistaken `\sin` removed.